# How to calculate a weird type of derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, proof-writing

I'm trying to understand Noether's theorem in the context of classical mechanics. And there is one type of expression involving taking a derivative of a multivariable function that I have never seen how to manipulate it. I will construct a simpler version of the expression I have in mind in terms of a function of single variable to make things simpler and I hope I can generalize the solution to the case I have in mind.

The expression:
Let $f$ be differentiable function, and $g$ be continous. How do we calculate the following limit:

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+hg(x)) -f(x)}h\ $

Intuitively it looks like it should be the derivative of $f$ at $x$. But how can we show that rigorously? Meaning using epsilon delta definition.

If anyone has the solution of the generalized version of this problem for multivariable functions it would be very helpful. Because it gets really complicated when we have the multivariable chain rule for twice composed functions and I'm lost.

The general case:
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x(t) +hg(x(t)),\ y(t)+h\frac{dg}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt})-f(x(t), y(t) )}h\ $

Comment: since $g$ is continuous its limit exists and is finite everywhere, implying that $hg(x)$ approaches $0$ for all $x$ as $h\to0$.

Comment: $ \frac{f(x+hg(x)) -f(x)}h =  \frac{f(x+hg(x)) -f(x)}{hg(x)} \cdot g(x) \to f'(x) g(x)$

Comment: @MartinR, that's a good answer - and would render better as one

Comment: That's an intuitive answer that I understand but don't know how to justify it rigoursly (using epsilon delta defenition).

Comment: @I0_0I: Can you see that $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+hg(x)) -f(x)}{hg(x)} = \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{f(x+k)-f(x)}{k} = f'(x)$ if $g(x) \ne 0$?

Comment: @I0_0I, if $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then you know that $\lim_{k\to0}\frac{f(x+k)-f(x)}{k} =f'(x)$, which means "for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$..." You don't need to ***find*** the $\delta$, but if you want to derive an expression for $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$, that would depend on the function $f$, and potentially the point $x$.

Comment: OK I see it now thanks all..

Comment: After I tried to generalize your answers I failed to do so, so I edit my question and I  included the general case I'm interested in. Can you give me a hint how to handle this please? What makes it difficult is that I no longer have one function g. I have two different functions so I can't divide by one of them to solve the problem.

Comment: If $x$ is differentiable at $t$, and $g$ is differentiable at $x(t)$, then your new expression is the directional derivative of $f$ at the point $(x(t),y(t))$, along the vector $\langle g(x(t)), g'(x(t)) \rangle$

Comment: But g and g' are functions not independent variables. I know that we can express it in terms of directional for independent variables. But how do we know the same thing hold is the argument is a function not an independent variable?

Comment: The limit is as $h\to0$. None of $t$, $x(t)$ ,$y(t)$, $g(x(t))$, or $g'(x(t))$ are changing.